# User defined function to do t-tests between two datasets

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, lapply

I'm a new user trying to figure out `lapply`.

I have two data sets with the same 30 variables in each, and I'm trying to run t-tests to compare the variables in each sample. My ideal outcome would be a table that lists each variable along with the t stat and the p-value for the difference in that variable between the two datasets.

I tried to design a function to do the t test, so that I could then use `lapply`. Here's my code with a reproducible example.

```
height<-c(2,3,4,2,3,4,5,6)
weight<-c(3,4,5,7,8,9,5,6)
location<-c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
data_test<-cbind(height,weight,location)
data_north<-subset(data_test,location==0)
data_south<-subset(data_test,location==1)
variables<-colnames(data_test)
compare_t_tests<-function(x){
  model<-t.test(data_south[[x]], data_north[[x]], na.rm=TRUE)
  return(summary(model[["t"]]), summary(model[["p-value"]]))
}
compare_t_tests(height)
```

which gets the error:

```
Error in data_south[[x]] : attempt to select more than one element
```

My plan was to use the function in `lapply` like this, once I figure it out.

```
 lapply(variables, compare_t_tests)
```

I'd really appreciate any advice. It seems to me like I might not even be looking at this right, so redirection would also be welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close.  There are just a few tweaks:

Data:

```
height <- c(2,3,4,2,3,4,5,6)
weight <- c(3,4,5,7,8,9,5,6)
location <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
```

Use `data.frame` instead of `cbind` to get a data frame with real names ...

```
data_test <- data.frame(height,weight,location)
data_north <- subset(data_test,location==0)
data_south <- subset(data_test,location==1)
```

Don't include `location` in the set of variables ...

```
variables <- colnames(data_test)[1:2] ## skip location
```

Use the model, not the summary; return a vector

```
compare_t_tests<-function(x){
   model <- t.test(data_south[[x]], data_north[[x]], na.rm=TRUE)
   unlist(model[c("statistic","p.value")])
}
```

Compare with the variable in quotation marks, not as a raw symbol:

```
compare_t_tests("height")
## statistic.t     p.value 
##   0.2335497   0.8236578
```

Using `sapply` will automatically collapse the results into a table:

```
sapply(variables,compare_t_tests)
##                height     weight
## statistic.t 0.2335497 -0.4931970
## p.value     0.8236578  0.6462352
```

You can transpose this (`t()`) if you prefer ...

Comment: you're welcome.  Technically [you're not supposed to use comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment) (voting and accepting are supposed to be enough thanks), but I